# gnuplot gives extraordinary large error estimates

Tags: gnuplot, curve-fitting

Today I tried to fit experimental data with a given theoretical model. Although the fit was fairly good, gnuplot returned extremely high errors:

```
Final set of parameters            Asymptotic Standard Error
=======================            ==========================

A               = 1.76654e-11      +/- 2.589e-06    (1.465e+07%)
g               = 0.000929911      +/- 1.006e-05    (1.082%)
offset          = 0.831727         +/- 0.005273     (0.634%)
x0              = 25.7152          +/- 3768         (1.465e+04%)
```

Especially, the error on x0 is an important measure for my following calculations. Obviously, this value is absolutely nonsense, as can be seen in the figure below.

**What do I have to do to get a meaningful error?**

[image: screenshot]

**MWE:**

```
f(x,x0,g) = -16.0*A*(g*(g**2.0-12.0*(x-x0)**2))/(pi*(g**2.0+4.0*(x-x0)**2.0)**3.0) + offset
FIT_LIMIT = 1e-16

A=-1e-3
g=1e-3
offset=0.8
x0 = 25.71514200

fit f(x,x0,g) "data" via A,g,offset,x0

plot "data", f(x,x0,g)
```

**Data:** [Link (pastebin)](http://pastebin.com/R5wXkLPe)

Comment: I can reproduce what you see, curious to learn what is going on actually.

Comment: Did you try to evaluate df/dA, df/dx0 etc? It gives you an idea about error propagation, and might teach you something.

Comment: Yes, I did error propagation analysis but that showed nothing unusual... In the end I concluded that it is somehow not possible using gnuplot although the fit itself was relatively fine. I chose to use (for the first time in my life) a commercial software with which it worked nicely.

Comment: If you want to try building gnuplot from the sources, there is a patch [#655 fit: alternative minimization packages](http://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/patches/655/) which allows you to select between different fitting libraries. I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are two aspects to this case.
0. I exclude the presence of a bug, but that could still be the case.

1. Check the actual definition of the Asymptotic st. error, and the other parameters of the fit, which in this case seem reasonable.
   Please check also the other details of the fitting:
   "degrees of freedom    (FIT_NDF)                        : 97
   rms of residuals      (FIT_STDFIT) = sqrt(WSSR/ndf)    : 0.0420015
   variance of residuals (reduced chisquare) = WSSR/ndf   : 0.00176412
   "

- 

From Gnuplot manual:

> the asymptotic standard errors are generally over-optimistic and should not be used for determining confidence levels, but are useful for qualitative purposes.

It may be that the fit is actual correct, but since you have many dof, and a complex function that's the best you can rigorously achieve.

2. There is an intrinsic limit into fitting. For example it depends on the starting values and sometimes you fall into some pits.

As a test I run the fitting starting with different starting values for the parameters.
(I renamed variables) and I created a second function with different parameters just to be sure we are all the time starting with new parameters.

```
f(x) = -16.0*A*(g*(g**2.0-12.0*(x-y)**2))/(pi*(g**2.0+4.0*(x-y)**2.0)**3.0)+B
g(x) = -16.0*AA*(gg*(gg**2.0-12.0*(x-yy)**2))/(pi*(gg**2.0+4.0*(x-yy)**2.0)**3.0)+BB
gnuplot> A=1e-3 ; g=1e-3; B =0.8 ; y = 25.71514200
gnuplot> AA=-1e-3 ; gg=1e-3; BB =0.8 ; yy = 25.71514200
```

(Basically I did a second fitting changing the sign of A)
Results of fitting f(x)

```sh
gnuplot> fit f(x) "data.dat" u 1:2 via A,B,g,y
iter      chisq       delta/lim  lambda   A             B             g             y            
[CUT]

After 2 iterations the fit converged.
final sum of squares of residuals : 487.102
rel. change during last iteration : -4.02829e-07

degrees of freedom    (FIT_NDF)                        : 97
rms of residuals      (FIT_STDFIT) = sqrt(WSSR/ndf)    : 2.24091
variance of residuals (reduced chisquare) = WSSR/ndf   : 5.02167

Final set of parameters            Asymptotic Standard Error
=======================            ==========================
A               = 0.000999999      +/- 585.1        (5.851e+07%)
B               = 0.8              +/- 2124         (2.655e+05%)
g               = 0.001            +/- 535.8        (5.358e+07%)
y               = 25.7408          +/- 1362         (5292%)

correlation matrix of the fit parameters:
                A      B      g      y      
A               1.000 
B              -0.999  1.000 
g              -1.000  0.999  1.000 
y               1.000 -1.000 -1.000  1.000
```

Result of fitting g(x)

```sh
gnuplot> fit g(x) "data.dat" u 1:2 via AA,BB,gg,yy
iter      chisq       delta/lim  lambda   AA            BB            gg            yy           
   0 5.0258343096e+02   0.00e+00  1.03e+03   -1.000000e-03   8.000000e-01   [CUT]
iter      chisq       delta/lim  lambda   AA            BB            gg            yy           

After 6 iterations the fit converged.
final sum of squares of residuals : 0.171225
rel. change during last iteration : -3.85774e-08

degrees of freedom    (FIT_NDF)                        : 97
rms of residuals      (FIT_STDFIT) = sqrt(WSSR/ndf)    : 0.0420144
variance of residuals (reduced chisquare) = WSSR/ndf   : 0.00176521

Final set of parameters            Asymptotic Standard Error
=======================            ==========================
AA              = -0.000999968     +/- 9.454e+07    (9.454e+12%)
BB              = 0.828332         +/- 240.8        (2.908e+04%)
gg              = 0.000999968      +/- 9.453e+07    (9.454e+12%)
yy              = 26.1206          +/- 3.798e+06    (1.454e+07%)

correlation matrix of the fit parameters:
                AA     BB     gg     yy     
AA              1.000 
BB             -0.040  1.000 
gg              1.000 -0.040  1.000 
yy             -0.110  0.998 -0.109  1.000 
gnuplot>
```

Not only the fitting are different, but in my case they are completely off (I have a different version of gnuplot).

Looking at the graphic I also notice that the graphic has 3 areas, two almost linear and one that looks like a well.
I am not surprised is not easy to find the proper function that matches all.

Have you tried to proceed fitting one parameter at the time, starting from X0, since it seems the most univocal one? ( you might as well assign it by eye, or use a parabolic approach to a subset of the data).

This is practically equivalent to do fitting with respect to derivates.
In this way you are reducing the number of constrain and you might land in a better fit.

Answer (score -2):

I think that problem is in using 3-parameter function. From the first line it seems that `x0` and `g` are variables. But in `fit` it's used as mixture of parameters (because of `via`...) and variables (because of `f(x,x0,g)`).

How many columns have got file "data"? It looks like that 2 is right answer.

Try this:

```
f(x) = -16.0*A*(g*(g**2.0-12.0*(x-x0)**2))/(pi*(g**2.0+4.0*(x-x0)**2.0)**3.0) + offset
FIT_LIMIT = 1e-16

A=-1e-3
g=1e-3
offset=0.8
x0 = 25.71514200

fit f(x) "data" via A,g,offset,x0

plot "data", f(x)
```

Comment: That gives identical results to the OP's results. In fact it is completely irrelevant how the values are given to the function which is to be evaluated.

Comment: Well, I am not convinced from this argument.
Variable and parameters are intrinsically different and usually people proceed to calculate them iteratively to avoid to find a bad solution.

Comment: @Cippo1987 Maybe people proceed differently, but not gnuplot. My point was, that both cases are evaluated identically by gnuplot

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry, you are totally right. As far as Gnuplot cares, there is no difference. 
I infact suspect that here the problem is more on the side of theory rather than gnuplot.